# Nontrivial example of a ring in which the union of ideals is an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, examples-counterexamples

If R is a field and it has two ideal and any union of two ideal is again ideal. But Can we give an example of commutative ring(necessarily not field) with 1 and union of two ideal is again ideal?

Answer (score 1):

Any uniserial ring (in the sense that the ideals are linearly ordered) has the property that unions of ideals are ideals.

So, for example, $F[[x]]$ for a field $F$, or $\mathbb Z/(p^n)$ for a prime $p$ and positive integer $n$, or [any of these DaRT results](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=1&H=76l&L=54).

(Among commutative rings) Uniserial rings are *exactly* the rings for which the union of any two ideals is an ideal. If $A$ and $B$ are two ideals, and $a\in A\setminus B$ and $b\in B\setminus A$, then it's easy to see $a+b\notin A\cup B$.